# How to access a resource avaialble in MainWindow from Control?

Tags: c#, wpf

I defined a `UserControl` where I insert a `TabItem` content previously available in `MainWindow`, I did this for organize better the code.

Anyway, I've several TabItem that use a static resource called `GroupedItems` this resource is available inside MainWindow:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>     
        <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding Matches}" x:Key="GroupedItems">
            <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
                <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="MatchNation" />
                <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="MatchLeague" />
            </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        </CollectionViewSource>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

in my control I've this:

```
<ListView Name="Playing" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource GroupedItems}}">
```

but the compiler cannot locate the resource 'cause I get this error:

> Cannot resolve the resource GroupedItems

this is why I have this resource in `MainWindow` resource, how can I access it from controls?

Comment: I think it would be best to pass the resource to your control through another bound property

Comment: @slawekwin if I have x control I need to pass this x times. I think it better have the resource `GroupedItems` in the MainWindow (in one place) and access from anywhere.

Comment: I meant to give a dependency property to your control and bind your static dictionary to all its instances in main window. It's just a general idea

Comment: Sometimes the error is shown in XAML while accessing static resources. But actually there is no error. Clean the project and rebuild and most of the time error is gone if you have all the names of static resources correctly written

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move it to app.xaml then it will become available for current project

```
<Application.Resources>
<ResourceDictionary>     
    <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding Matches}" x:Key="GroupedItems">
        <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
            <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="MatchNation" />
            <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="MatchLeague" />
        </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
</ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```